# Where can I find the rules for the Roc Pattern Storm Eagle?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I've seen that its rules exist, but not in which book or web supplement to find them. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for the Roc Pattern are in *Imperial Armour Volume 12 - The Fall of Orpheus*, from Forge World, p.151.

You can just about see this from the scanned table of contents (2nd image) on the [FW page for the book](http://www.forgeworld.co.uk/Warhammer-40000/Imperial_Armour_Books/IMPERIAL_ARMOUR_VOLUME_TWELVE_THE_FALL_OF_ORPHEUS.html). It's also [referenced on the 40K Wiki](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Eagle#Sources).